# android - passing a value through a onclick listener

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have the user enter in 2 numbers (a, b). It will subtract b from a to get c. (c=a-b). When c has a value, I want the user to be able to change the value of b and it will subtract from the new total of c. 
For example
user enters
10 for a
2 for b
it will return 8 (for c)
Then the user can change b to 5 and will subtract from c. so it will give a new total of 3. and will continue subtracting when the user clicks the button.

What I did so far:
I set up the onclicklistener to grab the string from a and b and did the subtraction. However, I dont know how to pass the new total (in the case c) out of the onclicklistener and back through to be subtracted from b.

I am fairly new to android so any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm sorry I dont have my code, I'm at work at the moment :)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can probably just keep track of of the value in the `OnClickListener`.

```
View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    double c;

    // in case you need to use C elsewhere
    public double getC() {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get A and B values
        // then use either
        c = a - b;
        // or I guess use 
        c = c - b;
    }
});

myButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Then when you need C, just call `myListener.getC();`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable c in such a scope that you can refer to it inside the onClickListener.